# Data request: how long do consumers wait for certain discounts, savings, and bargains?

Tags: data-request, economics, research, business, historical

I'd like to know where I can find data regarding consumers' willingness to wait for discounts, bargains, savings, and so forth. Units can be in time, or in time per discount percent, etc.

Related data such as whether consumers use the internet to cross-check prices, and if so, how often, would also be welcome.

I was going to try collecting the data myself, but I figure that economists/business analysts may have tried this data mining themselves (and thus, it wouldn't be wise to recreate the wheel, etc).